# Font height issue on the same line

Tags: html, css

**Example of problem:**
[image: Example of problem]

```
    <ol><li>
<span>01</span><h4>SOME TEXT</h4>
</li></ol>

#faq ol li h4
{

    padding-bottom: 16px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    max-width: 710px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: DINCE-Medium , Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
```

I have some issues with setting the number on the same line next to the heading with the same height as the heading background.

I really don't know how to set number in span because every time when I set to the number same height (font size) as h4 background it has a little bit bottom spacing  and that ruin it.

I tried reset padding and margin to span but I got same result.

I am grateful for every advice : ))

Answer (score 2):

It is practically impossible to set the height of the text to match the height of the box. Fonts are rendered slightly differently on different browsers and systems, so it will never become 100% pixel perfect. You can never have total control of the font rendering.

If you need pixel perfect, use an image. Otherwise try to get some statistics of what browsers and operating systems your visitors are using and try to make the design good enough for the majority of them.

Comment: couldn't you do it with svg? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-rendering

Comment: @jcuenod Yes, I would put that in the "use an image" category. You would want to use paths (not text) to get the pixel control.

Comment: Even if you use the `text-rendering` attribute in CSS you will have slightly different results in different systems, but it definitely something you can tweak to get it "close enough".